# Facebook Graph Api search events

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I thought it was a simple thing but I was wrong, I would like to have the list of public events of a page (such as the redbull)
I tried this but without luck:

```
/14226545351/events
```

Also I would like to know if it was possible to search for events by keyword, I tried this but without luck:

```
/search?q=run&type=event
```

I generated an access token, with the right permissions (I think) but in both cases I read

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> You can no longer use the /search endpoint with the following object
>   types:
>
> - event
> - group
> - page
> - user

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Event Search is not possible anymore, and the Events API in general is not possible as of now:

> ...apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access today.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to query event data using the facebook api https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/